# How to stop input resize on font-size change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been searching in stackoverflow for a question similar to mine because it is relatively simple, but I had no luck so far, so here it goes:

I have this input:

```
<input type="text" id="test"/>
```

With this css rule:

```
#test { font-size:14px; }
```

But when I run this with jquery:

```
 $('#test').click(function () {
     $(this).css('font-size', '14px');
 });
```

**The input box resizes to fit the new font-size**. Is it possible to stop this?
Vertical resizing is ok with me, it is the horizontal resize that kills me ;)

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bHknp/1/).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you already specify a width and height to the textbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set a `max width` property in your css
something like:

```
#test { 
  font-size:14px; 
  max-width: 150px;
}​
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to put width style on the text input.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `#test` css to

```
#test 
{ font-size:14px;height:20px;width:200px; }
```